# Weird BSCMAKE build error that I cannot diagnose. Turning off browse info is not an option

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, browse-information

I have a solution with about 10 C++ projects in Visual Studio 2017.  A few of them make use a post-build tool that requires me to build browse information.  One of them keeps failing on the BSCMAKE step virtually every time I make a code change with a very unhelpful error message.  The only way to fix it is to completely rebuild that project.  Every single time.

If turning off browse info were an option, I would do it.  But I can't.

This is the error message

```
1>------ Build started: Project: gsaxel, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>gsaxel_v15.vcxproj -> C:\Users\jmole\Documents\Dev\GSSdk\x64\Debug\v141\gsaxeld_v141.dll
1>BSCMAKE : error BK1505: cannot read from file 'C:\Users\jmole\Documents\Dev\GSdk\x64\Debug\v141\gsaxeld_v141.bsc'
1>Done building project "gsaxel_v15.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
StopOnFirstBuildError: Build cancelled because project "gsaxel_v15" failed to build.
Build has been canceled.
```

Again, if I clean and rebuild that one project, BSCMAKE has no problems and it builds fine.   But this happens almost every single time I make the slightest code change.  Even if it's only to a file in a completely separate DLL that this one merely links to.

**A few things I've checked:**

The disk on which I am building this code has 738 GB free space so it's not for lack of space.

I tried turning off incremental linking.  It had no effect

I tried adding a verbose ("/v") option to the BSCMAKE command line but all it added was a message about processing the first .SBR file

```
1>Processing: x64\Debug\v141\edgecrispness.sbr ..
```

But after that I get the same BSCMAKE error message.   If I go and delete that .SBR file and build again, it will recompile it the .CPP, regenerate the SBR and ***still*** give me the same BSCMAKE error.

I even tried excluding that one source file from the project altogether.  The problem still occurred (and my BSCMAKE verbose option just mentioned that it was processing the next .SBR file...)

I have gone through every source file in the DLL (there are only 6 .CPP files) to verify that none of them individually override the browse settings -- or any others actually.

Anyone have any ideas where I could look?

Comment: I haven't seen this error before, but the key thing to focus on is the error description: BSCMAKE : error BK1505: cannot read from file 'C:\Users\jmole\Documents\Dev\GelSightSdk\x64\Debug\v141\gsaxeld_v141.bsc'. Can you generate a SysInternals ProcMon trace, and filter on the filename in question? Is there some other process possibly locking the file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give that a shot.  I will admit it seems unlikely as repeated attempts at building the same project again will still fail with exactly the same error (until I completely rebuild).  But you never know, it might be just some weirdness like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
In the .vcxproj file I had an AdditionalOptions section.
Once I removed it, everything was fine.

Comment: could you explain why your solution solved the asked troubles?